# Improve Docker build speed for Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, docker, docker-compose, angular-cli

I've set up an Angular development workflow using Docker. However, building the docker and serving the Angular app is a bit slow and takes around ~7 minutes (considering all base images pre-downloaded).

**./package.json:**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "docker-serve-dev": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.development.yml up --build",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.6",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "5.0.1",
    "@nebular/auth": "3.3.0",
    "@nebular/bootstrap": "3.3.0",
    "@nebular/security": "3.3.0",
    "@nebular/theme": "3.3.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.4",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^10.1.0",
    "angular-tree-component": "8.3.0",
    "angular2-chartjs": "0.5.1",
    "angular2-toaster": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "ckeditor": "4.11.2",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.6.5",
    "echarts": "^4.1.0",
    "error-stack-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.1",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "leaflet": "1.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nebular-icons": "1.1.0",
    "ng-snotify": "^4.3.1",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.2",
    "ng2-completer": "2.0.8",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.4.0",
    "ngx-echarts": "^4.1.0",
    "normalize.css": "8.0.1",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^7.0.5",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.4.0",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "stacktrace-gps": "^3.0.2",
    "stacktrace-js": "^2.0.0",
    "tinymce": "4.5.7",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "typeface-exo": "0.0.61",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.6",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.2",
    "@types/d3-color": "1.2.2",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.16",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.4.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "2.0.12",
    "husky": "1.3.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "prettier-tslint": "^0.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "stylelint": "9.10.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.1",
    "tslint-language-service": "^0.9.9",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "lint",
      "problemMatcher": {
        "base": "$tslint5",
        "fileLocation": "relative"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**./docker-compose.development.yml:**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  cc-ui-docker-service:
    container_name: cc-ui-dev-container
    image: cc-ui-dev-dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/development.dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - './:/usr/share/app'
      - /app/node_modules/
    ports:
      - 4200:80
    ## set your startup file here
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --watch --poll=2000']
```

**./.docker/development.dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:10.15.1-alpine

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/share/app
WORKDIR /usr/share/app

# add `/usr/share/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/share/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/share/app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /usr/share/app/package-lock.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.3

# add app
COPY . /usr/share/app
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["ng", "--host=0.0.0.0","--watch", "--poll=2000", "serve"]
```

How I can improve the build time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying the entire node_modules folder into your container, try to only copy the package.json and after that run ”npm install”. The node_module folder doesn’t have to be copied over to the container since ”npm install” installs all the necessary modules in the container, it reads all dependencies from package.json.

This will reduce building time :)

Answer (score 3):

You can to build an application outside the docker and copy only `dist` folder into  [nginx docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx).

After then you don't need to install `node_modules` evrey time.

**Dockerfile example**

```
FROM nginx:latest
ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow
COPY ./dist/my-app /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

**nginx.conf example**

```
server {
  server_name my-app;
  root /var/www/frontend/src;

  try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) when building images with Docker.

An example `Dockerfile` would be:

```
FROM node:10 as build
WORKDIR /home
COPY package.json package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm build # or any other command to package

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /home/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Thats it :)